# Ubuntu 20.04 runs OK from USB but it takes too long to install on the HDD

Tags: dell, usb-installation

I am successfully running Ubuntu 20.04 from an USB drive, but why does it take too long to install on the HDD? My laptop is a Dell Inspiron n5050 circa 2012. I have a raw hard disk, and I want to install an Ubuntu 20.04 single boot on it.

Comment: How long is "too long"? What do you mean by "*want to make it single boot*?"

Comment: It last for more that 10 hrs. I formatted my hdd so if it installs it would be single os on my machine.

Comment: A normal install takes 30-60 minutes. Something is wrong with your installer or hardware.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: I have seen the installer get stuck a few times. Format the disk and start over. If that does not work check the MD5SUM of the ISO.

Comment: I have also seen it a few times. Replacing the hard drive worked for me.

Comment: I recommend that you **[edit]** this question to: *(a)* include the information you've provided in comments thus far, *(b)* indicate if you've verified the integrity of the downloaded ISO as C.S.Cameron mentioned (in my experience, problems like what you've described, even when the live environment exhibits no performance problem, usually come down to this--though karel has a good point that it very well may be hardware a problem affecting the target device), and *(c)* if possible, to say *what the installer said it was doing* when it stopped making progress.

Comment: Minimum the reviewers of this question seem to want at least a description of what the Ubuntu installer screen looks like when it stops installing and hangs. If you can remember anything that was written on the screen such as % completed it would be even better. Can you provide a link to a photo from your phone so I can put something concrete in the empty space in your question?

Comment: How can a question edited by karel possibly lack clarity? Looks perfect to me.

Comment: The desktop I am working with have the same issue as well since it has HDD instead of SSD. Takes more than a few hours to install Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error a few times when installing Ubuntu on old hardware. The Ubuntu installer boots normally, and somewhere in the middle of downloading packages the Ubuntu installer stops and hangs there indefinitely.

[image]
<sup>**Input/output error in 20.04 installer**</sup>

I knew it wasn't the Ubuntu live USB drive's fault because I had used the same USB flash drive to install Ubuntu on other computers. Replacing the internal hard drive worked for me. Your laptop is 8 years old, so it's possible that its hard drive has too many bad sectors. Replacement hard drives and even SSDs are inexpensive, so this is a good time to upgrade your laptop.